# how to keep html table layout fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a problem with HTML table layout. I have created an HTML form and layout the form using HTML table :

```
  <form id="form1">
    <table class="ui-widget">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="CreateName">Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="CreateName" name="Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="CreateDate">Date</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="CreateDate" name="Date" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            .. 
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>     
   </form>
```

I have inserted jquery validation on form fields. Now my problem is when validation error shown, than whole table layout is affected. I used :

```
        table-layout: fixed;
```

But still it is not working. How can i get rid of this issue ?

Comment: Can you show us your code on jsfiddle.net to play around with?

Comment: Where are you showing the validation errors?

Comment: My guess would be that you need to set a fixed width for the `table` element

Comment: Validation errors dynamically insert by jquery.validation plugin just after the related input text field

Comment: If html elements introduced by the validation plugin don't have enough space, the table cell sizes will be forced to adjust regardless of cell size afaik.

Comment: FWIW, tables should not be used for layout...

Comment: will have a lot more control by wrapping the inner TD with DIV and when it is set position relative can use any position you want on it's children. Why use a table in the first place? Have you considered some css widths on your TD's also?